# Computational time forward-propagation vs. back-propagation in neural network?

Tags: neural-network, time-complexity

What are the computational time differences of carrying out the dot products etc. in forward- propagation vs. the derivatives etc. in back-propagation for neural networks? Also, is the weights update procedure considered part of the backward pass computational time? Does the ratio forward pass/backward pass comp. time change depending on architecture e.g. CNN, RNN, LSTM? Thank you.